# Trying to use len() to print a message indicating the number of people i'm inviting, but im getting an error

Tags: python, list

Trying to use len() to print a message indicating the number of people I'm inviting, but getting an error on the print function of people.len()

## guest list Program

```
      people = ['roosevelt','Tom','Chief']
      print(f"{people[0].title()}, your are invited ")
      print(f"{people[1].title()}, your are invited")
      print(f"{people[2].title()}, your are invited")

      #trying to print amount of people invited using the people variable
      print(f"{people.len()}, are coming to the party")
```

## Error

```
# File "/Users/eliteghost/Desktop/Python/3.9.py", line 9, in <module>
# print(f"{people.len()}, are coming to the party")
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'len'
```

Answer (score 2):

The only mistake you made is that you are using wrongly the [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function, as it's not a method from lists, but a built-in function from Python.

So, basically, change this:

```
print(f"{people.len()}, are coming to the party")
```

Into this

```
print(f"{len(people)}, are coming to the party")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```py
people = ['roosevelt', 'Tom', 'Chief']
print(f"{people[0].title()}, your are invited ")
print(f"{people[1].title()}, your are invited")
print(f"{people[2].title()}, your are invited")

# trying to print amount of people invited using the people variable
print(f"{len(people)}, are coming to the party")
```

Comment: This solves the problem.  It would be a better answer if it explained why this change solves the problem.

Comment: The problem rise with the **len** function which is not used properly. 
[Python Len method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)